# Coverage couldn't run 'manage.py' as Python code

Tags: python, django, code-coverage

I am using Coverage to measure my test code, but I stuck on a weird problem. I tried the command according to [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/advanced/#integration-with-coverage-py):

```
coverage run --source='.' manage.py test myapp
```

But I got this error:

> Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
>   Couldn't run 'manage.py' as Python code: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>   (manage.py, line 16)

It works correctly using `python manage.py test myapp`.

Here is my manage.py (I didn't modify anything).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mytestsite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What am I missing exactly?

I ran my code and coverage in virtualenv, but I don't think this could be a problem.

**ENV:**

```
Python 3.6.8
Django 2.2.3
Coverage 4.5.4
```

Comment: Coverage is using Python 2 for some reason. How did you install it?

Comment: I created a virtual env `python3 -m virtualenv .env` and source, and then I can run coverage.

Comment: That command won't install coverage.  What does "which coverage" show for you?

Comment: I type `which coverage` in virtualenv, it shows `/usr/local/bin/coverage`.

Comment: @Corey that result means you didn't install `coverage` in that virtual env, and it's using the one in `/usr/local/bin` instead, which is apparently running python version 2.

Answer (score 3):

By default, coverage may be using python2 instead of python 3. 
You can use:

```
coverage3 run --source='.' manage.py test myapp
```